# How to mock standart perl opendir and readdir functions?

Tags: perl, mocking

I'm writing test for function which gets list of all `*.pm` files in current directory.

Here is function:

```
sub get_inspected_modules_list {
    my ( $dir ) = @_;
    opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!;
    my @files;
    while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
        next unless (-f "$dir/$file");   # skip nested dirs
        next unless ($file =~ m/\.pm$/); # push only *.pm
        push @files, $file;
    }
    closedir($dh);
    return \@files
}
```

I tried to use [Test::MockFile::DirHandle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockFile::DirHandle) for test, but it prints `No such file or directory` error:

```
subtest "get_inspected_modules_list" => sub {

    my $handle = Test::MockFile::DirHandle->new(
        "/fake/path", 
        [qw/Foo.pm Bar.pm Baz.pm test.txt 1.pl/]
    );

    warn Dumper get_inspected_modules_list( '/fake/path' ); # error

};
```

How to mock opendir/readdir calls ?

Comment: Are you also calling `use Test::MockFile`? That's where the mock `opendir` and `readdir` functions are installed.

Comment: Test::MockFile::DirHandle specifically says you shouldn't be using it directly; it's a class Test::MockFile uses internally.

Answer (score 1):

Right usage is

```
my $mocked_dir = Test::MockFile->dir("/fake/path", [ 'Foo.pm', 'bar.pl' ] );

opendir(my $dh, "/fake/path") or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    print "$file ";    # will print '. .. Foo.pm bar.pl'
}        

undef $mocked_dir;
```

So, instead of `Test::MockFile::DirHandle` you should use [Test::MockFile->dir](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockFile#dir)